# Search and replace key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im trying to serach the key named "SerialNumber" in array of objects and replace with "SNo"

```
var object = [{
    "SerialNumber": 001,
    "name": "user1"
}, {
    "SerialNumber": 002,
    "name": "user2"
}];
if ('SerialNumber' in object[0]) {
    object.forEach(function (key) {
        key.SNo = key.SerialNumber;
        delete key.SerialNumber;
    });
}
console.log(object)
```

if `object = []`, then the above code is not working. Is there any better approach (with good performance) to search the key in array of objects and replace with the new key.

Comment: Maybe do a check to see if the array is empty before you access `object[0]`
As in 

`if (object.length > 0) { ... }`

And maybe don't call the array object.

Comment: Note: your current code doesn't "search" - you test for a property of that name in the first element only, and if it exists you then process every element in the array whether they have a `SerialNumber` property or not.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and check if the key exist.

```js
function replace(oldKey, newKey, array) {
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        if (oldKey in o) {
            o[newKey] = o[oldKey];
            delete o[oldKey];
        }
    });
}

var object = [{ "SerialNumber": '001', "name": "user1" }, { "SerialNumber": '002', "name": "user2" }];
replace('SerialNumber', 'SNo', object);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you switched `if` and `foreach`. `object` is an Array, so you can forEach through items, and there check for your condition.

```
var object = [
    {
        "SerialNumber": 001,
        "name": "user1"
    },
    {
        "SerialNumber": 002,
        "name": "user2"
    }
];

object.forEach(function (item)  {
    if (item.SerialNumber !== undefined) {
        item.SNo = item.SerialNumber;
        delete item.SerialNumber;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
object.forEach(function(obj){
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty("SerialNumber")){
    obj["SNo"] = obj["SerialNumber"];
    delete obj["SerialNumber"];
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't use `for...in` with arrays.

Comment: Thanks for addressing. May i know the reason please? @MaxArt

Comment: Thank you. I got the reason :) @MaxArt

Comment: Perfect. Now, if you edit your snippet accordingly I'll remove the -1.

Comment: No, that's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the if condition into the forEach callback.
Otherwise it will only look for the SerialNumber of the first element and crash if it doesn't exists.

```
var array = [{
    "SerialNumber": 001,
    "name": "user1"
}, {
    "SerialNumber": 002,
    "name": "user2"
}];
array.forEach(function (element) {
    if(element.SerialNumber) {
        element.SNo = element.SerialNumber;
        delete element.SerialNumber;
    }
});
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the key after getting the objects from array.

```
object.forEach(function (key) {
    if ('SerialNumber' in key) {
        key.SNo = key.SerialNumber;
        delete key.SerialNumber;
    }
});
```

It will work if the object has no element.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the key of the object in a array then you better prefer mapping the array elements to itself.

Here is an example.

```js
var object = [{
        "SerialNumber": 001,
        "name": "user1"
        }, {
        "SerialNumber": 002,
        "name": "user2"
       }];
    object = object.map(function(value) {
       var tempObj = value;
       if (tempObj.SerialNumber) {
         tempObj.SNo = tempObj.SerialNumber;
         delete tempObj.SerialNumber;
       }
       return tempObj;
    });

    console.log(object);
```